# Do all nerves in the body end at the tongue?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, central-nervous-system

I saw this someone but have  searched on google to affirm or deny it, but didnt find anything on all nerves ending in the tongue. Please help

Answer (score 1):

No, nerve endings are where they communicate with muscles (motor nerves) or the ends are where information is sensed, like touch or taste (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_nerve_ending).

You could probably say that all nerves start in the brain but they spread out and end everywhere. http://www.innerbody.com/image/nervov.html

Answer (score 0):

***No*** all nerves do not innervate the tongue.

Out of the 12 pairs of cranial nerves only three nerves innervate the tongue; the pharyngeal part of the tongue is supplied by the ***glossopharyngeal nerve*** (IX) and the oral part is suppled by the lingual nerve [a branch of the mandibular branch (V3) of the ***trigeminal nerve*** (V)] and by the chorda tympani [a branch of the ***facial nerve***(VII)]. Apart from them the intrinsic and extrinsic muscles of tongue is supplied by ***Hypoglossal*** (XII).

The rest of the eight nerves along with C.N IX, V and VII have different extracranial destinations.

For e.g.- The first cranial nerve originating from olfactory bulb of fore brain reach the olfactory mucosa in the upper part of the nasal cavity.

[image]

P.S. To understand the extracranial course of cranial nerves read this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranial_nerves#Exiting_the_skull_and_Extracranial_Course) page.

Besides here's a diagram that roughly illustrates the major areas of innervation of Cranial nerves.

[image]